# Scala StackOverflows when recursion happends

Tags: scala, graph-algorithm

Hi I a have BronKerbosch algorithm for detecting the communities which is implemented using scala. It has a dataset which have more than 100000 nodes. When I run the code it gives an error saying stackoverflows. I have added the @tailrec annotation too. Below I have added the code as well as the error

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.graphx.Graph.graphToGraphOps
import org.slf4j.{Logger, LoggerFactory}
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.collection.mutable.{ArrayBuffer, Set => MutableSet}
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

class BronKerbosch[VD: ClassTag, ED: ClassTag](sc: SparkContext,
                                           inputGraph: Graph[VD, ED])  {



  private val logger: Logger = 
  LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[BronKerbosch[VD, ED]]);

  private val sparkContext: SparkContext = sc;

  private var graph: Graph[VD, ED] = inputGraph;

  private var neighbourVerticesMap = 
  graph.collectNeighborIds(EdgeDirection.Either)
  .collect().map(vertex => (vertex._1.asInstanceOf[Long], vertex._2))
  .toMap;

  def runAlgorithm = {

    logger.info("Starting BronKerbosch Algorithm");
    var potentialClique = Array[Long]()
    var candidates = graph.vertices.map(vertex => 
    vertex._1.asInstanceOf[Long]).collect().to[ArrayBuffer];

    var alreadyFound = ArrayBuffer[Long]();

    var cliques = ArrayBuffer[Array[Long]]()

    findCliques(potentialClique, candidates, alreadyFound, cliques);

    cliques;
  }


  private def findCliques(potentialClique: Array[Long],candidates: ArrayBuffer[Long], alreadyFound: ArrayBuffer[Long],cliques: ArrayBuffer[Array[Long]]): Unit = {

    if (candidates.isEmpty && alreadyFound.isEmpty) {
      cliques.append(potentialClique)

    }
    @tailrec
    var originalCandidates = candidates
    candidates.foreach { candidateVertex =>
    {
     var neighbourVertices = neighbourVerticesMap.getOrElse(candidateVertex, Array[Long]())

     findCliques((potentialClique :+ candidateVertex).distinct,candidates.intersect(neighbourVertices),alreadyFound.intersect(neighbourVertices), cliques)
  }


  }
 }
 }
```

Below is the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at 
scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.findEntry(HashTable.scala:132)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.findEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.apply(HashMap.scala:64)
at scala.collection.SeqLike$$anonfun$occCounts$1.apply(SeqLike.scala:481)
at scala.collection.SeqLike$$anonfun$occCounts$1.apply(SeqLike.scala:481)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:35)
at scala.collection.SeqLike$class.occCounts(SeqLike.scala:481)
at scala.collection.SeqLike$class.intersect(SeqLike.scala:469)
at scala.collection.AbstractSeq.intersect(Seq.scala:41)
at com.creative.graphx.BronKerbosch$$anonfun$com$creative$graphx$BronKerbosch$$findCliques$1.apply$mcVJ$sp(BronKerbosch.scala:57)
at com.creative.graphx.BronKerbosch$$anonfun$com$creative$graphx$BronKerbosch$$findCliques$1.apply(BronKerbosch.scala:53)
at com.creative.graphx.BronKerbosch$$anonfun$com$creative$graphx$BronKerbosch$$findCliques$1.apply(BronKerbosch.scala:53)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at com.creative.graphx.BronKerbosch.com$creative$graphx$BronKerbosch$$findCliques(BronKerbosch.scala:53)
at com.creative.graphx.BronKerbosch$$anonfun$com$creative$graphx$BronKerbosch$$findCliques$1.apply$mcVJ$sp(BronKerbosch.scala:57)
at com.creative.graphx.BronKerbosch$$anonfun$com$creative$graphx$BronKerbosch$$findCliques$1.apply(BronKerbosch.scala:53)
at com.creative.graphx.BronKerbosch$$anonfun$com$creative$graphx$BronKerbosch$$findCliques$1.apply(BronKerbosch.scala:53)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at com.creative.graphx.BronKerbosch.com$creative$graphx$BronKerbosch$$findCliques(BronKerbosch.scala:53)
at com.creative.graphx.BronKerbosch$$anonfun$com$creative$graphx$BronKerbosch$$findCliques$1.apply$mcVJ$sp(BronKerbosch.scala:57)
at com.creative.graphx.BronKerbosch$$anonfun$com$creative$graphx$BronKerbosch$$findCliques$1.apply(BronKerbosch.scala:53)
at com.creative.graphx.BronKerbosch$$anonfun$com$creative$graphx$BronKerbosch$$findCliques$1.apply(BronKerbosch.scala:53)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at com.creative.graphx.BronKerbosch.com$creative$graphx$BronKerbosch$$findCliques(BronKerbosch.scala:53)
```

What will be the best way to solve this ?

Comment: it would really help if the code was aligned correctly

Comment: an MCV would be nice too https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have formatted the code, but for some reason when I copied the code here, the formatted code was not aligned

Comment: @Ethan No! No no no no no no no! Code with an error report like that is code not working as intended. Code which DOESN'T work as intended is PER DEFINITON off-topic for Code Review!

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems with this code, but it is certainly not tail recursive.

Tail recursion requires that the function executes only one recursive call, and that call must be the last action in the function. (There may be multiple calls in the code, but only one can be called for any given path through the code)

In your code the recursive call to `findCliques` is inside a `foreach` loop, so it is potentially called multiple times, once for each candidate. This alone could be the reason for the stack overflow.

Your `@tailrec` annotation does not work because it needs to be before the function definition, not in the middle of the function.

Other problems with the code include bad formatting, unnecessary use of `var`, unused values (`originalCandidates`), and too many mutable data structures.

Comment: Hi Tim thanks for the answer, I used var without using val to make every variable mutable

Comment: @Supun You only need to use `var` if you are going to re-assign a variable. That is, if you are going to put it on the left-hand side of an assignment. Your code doesn't re-assign anything, so you can always use `val`. If you have a `val` that holds a mutable object you can change the object, you just can't make the variable refer to a different object.

Comment: It's worth adding that many classical algorithms just don't work with big data. Things aren't all stored in the same place, and the scope just grows too big. A Spark/GraphX clique finding algorithm will likely involve multiple rounds of message passing, possibly with pregel.